# An arithmetic progression problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

The question was:

> An AP starts with a positive fraction and every alternate term is an integer. If the sum of the first $11$ terms is $33$, find the fourth term.

I considered the first term to be $a$ and common difference to be $d$. So I used the formula for sum of arithmetic progressions $S_n=\frac n2[2a+(n-1)d]$ and found

$$\frac {11}{2}(2a+10d)=33$$

$$\implies a+5d=3$$

Now I saw that $a=d= \frac12$ quite clearly as that's the only way the 6th term could've could've $3$, as the AP is clearly

$\frac 12$, $1$, $\frac 32$, $2$, $\frac 52$, $3$ (6th term is $3$)

But what if I had got the equation of a term $a+nd= a_n$ such that $n$ is a much larger number? How would I have solved it that way?

Comment: Can you clarify why you think the 6th term is 5? Note that $ a = d = 1/2 $ doesn't yield $ a_6 = 5$.

Comment: If $a+(n-2)d,a+nd$ are integers, $2d$ should be integer

Comment: @Calvin Lin check the edits I made in my post

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee can you please elaborate it? Edit: I got it, though I think it would be better if you explain it for others reading this post in the future. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generalize the problem, consider an arithmetic progression in which the first term is a positive fraction, every alternate term is an integer, and the sum of the first $11$ terms is $S$.

If we take the convention that the general term of the progression is
$a_k = a + kd,$ where $a_0 = a$ is the first term in the progression,
then the conditions of the problem imply that $a_1$ and $a_3$ are integers.
Therefore $a_3 - a_1 = 2d$ is also an integer,
and therefore $d$ is a multiple of $\frac12.$

Depending on what we mean by "positive fraction,"
for a large enough $S$ the problem no longer has a unique solution.
If "positive fraction" merely means a positive number that is not an integer,
then if $S = 88$ then two possible solutions for the progression
$a_k = a+kd$ starting at $a_0 = a$ are

$$a = \frac12, \ d = \frac32;$$
$$a = \frac{11}2, \ d = \frac12.$$

In general (under this interpretation) we will always have $a_5 = \frac S{11},$ and the only requirement for a solution for a given $S$ is that
$\frac S{11} - 5d > 0$, which (given that $d$ is a multiple of $\frac12$)
implies that $\frac S{11} - 5d \geq \frac12$ or
$S - 55d \geq \frac{11}2$;
if we let $d = m + \frac12$ for integer $m \geq 0$
(that is, $d$ is a multiple of $\frac12$ but not an integer),
then $S - 55\left(m + \frac12\right) \geq \frac{11}2$,
which is equivalent to $S \geq 33 + 55m.$
Clearly there is no solution if $S < 33,$
and if $S < 88$ there can be only one solution (in which $d = \frac12$).

Note that since $a_5$ is an integer, since $a = a_0 = a_5 - 5d,$ and since $d$ is a multiple of $\frac12,$ it follows that $a$ also is a multiple of $\frac12.$

If "positive fraction" means a number strictly between $0$ and $1,$ then the only possible value of $a$ is $a = \frac12$ and there is at most one solution.

Note that under either of the interpretations given above,
if there is a solution at all, there is a solution in which $d = \frac12.$
Also, since $S = 11a_5,$ and $a_5$ is an integer, $S$ is a multiple of $11.$
And if $S \geq 33 + 55m$ for a non-negative integer $m,$
then there also are solutions in which $d$ can be any odd multiple  of $\frac12$ from $\frac12$ itself up to $m + \frac12.$
That is, there are two solutions if $S = 88$ (shown above),
three solutions if $S = 143$, and so forth.

Comment: Alright, so in my question, there is only 1 value for $d$, i.e., $\frac12$ and had it been such that $S>87$ then there would have been more solutions. Can you specify how many solutions for $d$ I would have got then? Is it $2$? I would have tried to evaluate it myself but it's 2 in the morning here and I am sleepy, and thanks a ton!

Comment: Yes, two solutions when $S=88,$ one with $d=\frac12$ and one with $d=\frac32,$ if it is OK for $a$ to be greater than $1.$ If $S$ is large enough there can be more solutions.

Comment: Alright, thanks